# Find Product in DB using Barcode Scanner - Java Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want a search function in my Java App. But I want it done using Barcode reader. I want to implement Barcode scanner.

My Problem is. I want to Scan a Product barcode and after scanning it will show the product details from the database. Help guys.

I dont have code right now. I dont even integrate barcode to java. Please help

Comment: SO is not a free code service, instead we help you with problems in your existing code. See [what is on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to understand how to ask a good question. In short: write some code and come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, however the question is too poor quality for Stack Overflow. You haven't shown any effort. You're required to attempt to find a solution on your own, make an attempt at the coding, and provide reproducible example code in order to ask a question here. This question shows no effort. The answer is readily available on Stack Overflow and Google.

Comment: Im here for help and not for anything. AND I have my code thats why i need help. dont say i dont even have my code. If youre here to answer not related then Go HOME

Comment: Both of you please.

Comment: what kind of app your going to develop ? is GUI  or non GUI app?

Comment: i am working java GUI

Comment: It's simple. Barcode scanner is a input device like keyboard, just move your cursor to search text box. then scan the bar code, it'll print the barcode info to the text box with enter.

Comment: But how can i get item on DB?

Comment: What i want is if i scan the barcode the product in the db that have the code will show.

Comment: Product info should have pre updated in db for a specific barcode. Barcode  must be a unique value.

Comment: yes. I will save barcode in db after that. I will retrieve in By scanning barcode after Scanning. Then it will show. Do you know the code for that? have any example?

Answer (score 0):

Please check how to implement this:

You can use: [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)